# SQL query to replace | in address field to front

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two columns in my table

```
Address_line_1 varchar(100),Address_line_2 varchar(100)
```

Now it hold some address fields using the pipe '|' as a separator. But the data is in back to front.

E.g. Field Value: `BEDFORD SQUARE|50`
I need output to be : `50 BEDFORD SQUARE`

And other condition is Address_line_1 is empty, then Address_line_1 = Address_line_2.  Then Address_line_2 is then empty

```
CASE WHEN ADDRESS_LINE_2 LIKE '%|%' 
   THEN RIGHT(ADDRESS_LINE_2, charindex('|', reverse(ADDRESS_LINE_2)) - 1)
```

I have tried above query but no success.

Sample data and script :

```
declare @tab table ( Address_line_1 varchar(100),Address_line_2 varchar(100))

insert into @tab values('BEDFORD SQUARE|50','')
insert into @tab values('','BEDFORD SQUARE|70')
insert into @tab values('','ABC')

select *,CASE WHEN ADDRESS_LINE_1 LIKE '%|%' THEN RIGHT(ADDRESS_LINE_1, charindex('|', reverse(ADDRESS_LINE_1)) - 1) end  from @tab


Address_line_1                                                                                       Address_line_2                                                                                       
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BEDFORD SQUARE|50                                                                                                                                                                                         50
                                                                                                     BEDFORD SQUARE|70                                                                                    NULL
                                                                                                     ABC
```

Comment: Can you also post some sample data along with expected result set so that we can gain a better understanding of the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I have updated question with sample data.. you can see using case.. it create a new column with 50 value only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  CASE 
                WHEN Address_line_1 = '' THEN Address_line_2
                ELSE Address_line_1 
            END Address_line
    FROM @tab
)
SELECT  *,
        CASE 
            WHEN Address_line LIKE '%|%'
            THEN RIGHT(Address_line,CHARINDEX('|',REVERSE(Address_line))-1) +
                 ' ' + LEFT(Address_line,CHARINDEX('|',Address_line)-1)
            ELSE Address_line
        END Result
FROM CTE;
```

The results are:

```
╔═══════════════════╦═══════════════════╗
║   Address_line    ║      Result       ║
╠═══════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║ BEDFORD SQUARE|50 ║ 50 BEDFORD SQUARE ║
║ BEDFORD SQUARE|70 ║ 70 BEDFORD SQUARE ║
║ ABC               ║ ABC               ║
╚═══════════════════╩═══════════════════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative answer because I'm not a big CTE fan, probably not much functionally better or worse in any meaningful way though:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Address_line,CHARINDEX('|',Address_line)+1,LEN(Address_line))
  + CASE WHEN Address_line LIKE '%|%' THEN ' ' ELSE '' END
  + SUBSTRING(Address_line, 0, CHARINDEX('|',Address_line))
FROM (
  SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(Address_line_1,''), Address_line_2) AS Address_line
  FROM @tab
) t
```